# ¿Cómo almacenar diferentes tipos de datos?

Tags: c++, c

Estoy creando un programa donde pueda almacenar distintos tipos de datos, entre ellos correos electrónicos. Tengo el problema de que no puedo guardar un correo que contenga números por el tipo de variable, quisiera saber: **¿Es posible almacenar un correo con esas características en C/C++?**

Comment: C y C++ tienen soluciones diferentes. En C tienes que usar un `char[]`, en C++ tienes acceso a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Para almacenar diferentes tipos de datos en C puedes usar estructuras (**struct**). Una estructura te permitirá almacenar tipos como `int, long, float, char`, etc. Como mencionan en los comentarios el tipo `char` te podría serivir para los correos.

```
struct Nombre{
   tipo1 nombrevar1;
   tipo2 nombrevar2; 
};
```

También si requieres definir tus propios tipos puedes usar `typedef Tipo nombreNuevotipo;`

Un ejemplo creando una estructura llamada Datos con sus propios tipos definidos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef bool Booleano;
typedef char Cadena[30];

typedef struct{
  Cadena id;
  Cadena nombre;
  Cadena email;
  Booleano isDisponible;
}Datos;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  struct Datos datos;
  strcpy(datos.id,"1");
  strcpy(datos.nombre,"Horacio");
  strcpy(datos.correo,"usuario,datos@hotmail.com");
  datos.isDisponible = true;
  //...  
  return 0;
}
```

Con esto puedes crear tus propias estructuras y almacenar diferentes tipos de datos.